# First Defined here in g++ from class to namespace

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, g++, multiple-definition-error

I have read many questions like this and I am not 100% sure if mine's any different. I have searched quite a lot for the right answer but most of the answers were around macro gaurds. I had a custom string class that I derived from `std::string`, and later on since I was using that project in real world so I did not want to derive std::string just for the sake of extending functionality. So I moved the functions from customString.h into utils_string.h. Here is the definition:

```
#ifndef OPS_TOOLKIT_UTILS_STRING_H
#define OPS_TOOLKIT_UTILS_STRING_H
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

namespace utils{
  namespace string{

const std::string kilikeDelimiter = "%";

void tolower(std::string& str){
    //CODE
}

bool iequals(const std::string& str1,const std::string& str2){
    //CODE
}
bool ilike(const std::string& str,const std::string& pattern){
    //CODE
}
std::string prependAndAppendILikeDelimiter(const std::string& str) {
    //CODE
}
} //namespace string
} //namespace utils

#endif
```

and I get complains about `...first defined here` and here is exact output from compiler. Note: no class here

> /tmp/ccCFVTXP.o: In function `utils::string::tolower(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)':
>   listings.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of`utils::string::tolower(std::basic_string, std::allocator >&)'
>   /tmp/cczDtRdT.o:listing.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
>   /tmp/ccCFVTXP.o: In function `utils::string::iequals(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
>   listings.cpp:(.text+0x55): multiple definition of`utils::string::iequals(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'
>   /tmp/cczDtRdT.o:listing.cpp:(.text+0x55): first defined here
>   /tmp/ccCFVTXP.o: In function `utils::string::ilike(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
>   listings.cpp:(.text+0x118): multiple definition of`utils::string::ilike(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'
>   /tmp/cczDtRdT.o:listing.cpp:(.text+0x118): first defined here
>   /tmp/ccCFVTXP.o: In function `utils::string::prependAndAppendILikeDelimiter(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
>   listings.cpp:(.text+0x484): multiple definition of`utils::string::prependAndAppendILikeDelimiter(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'
>   /tmp/cczDtRdT.o:listing.cpp:(.text+0x484): first defined here
>   /tmp/ccifZISK.o: In function `utils::string::tolower(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)':
>   match_count.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of`utils::string::tolower(std::basic_string, std::allocator >&)'
>   /tmp/cczDtRdT.o:listing.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
>   /tmp/ccifZISK.o: In function `utils::string::iequals(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
>   match_count.cpp:(.text+0x55): multiple definition of`utils::string::iequals(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'
>   /tmp/cczDtRdT.o:listing.cpp:(.text+0x55): first defined here
>   /tmp/ccifZISK.o: In function `utils::string::ilike(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
>   match_count.cpp:(.text+0x118): multiple definition of`utils::string::ilike(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'
>   /tmp/cczDtRdT.o:listing.cpp:(.text+0x118): first defined here
>   /tmp/ccifZISK.o: In function `utils::string::prependAndAppendILikeDelimiter(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
>   match_count.cpp:(.text+0x484): multiple definition of`utils::string::prependAndAppendILikeDelimiter(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'
>   /tmp/cczDtRdT.o:listing.cpp:(.text+0x484): first defined here
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I am sorry for whole mess but I didn't want to miss anything for anyone who has come across similar problem.

One more thing; where it says **match_count.cpp** **listing.cpp** and **listings.cpp** it's just using the functions defined in ::utils::string::function()

Answer (score 4):

A header file cannot *define* code unless it is explicitly `inline`.  Otherwise (because the preprocessor works like a giant copy/paste machine) it is as if the functions are defined once for every file that does a `#include`.

So add `inline` to each of those, or put them in a single `.cpp`, but not in a header.

Comment: @Kavin Thanks for the suggestion, but not a good idea. This is lazy solution for functions that have many lines. inline function is good for functions having less than ~10 lines. This is good for smaller functions but my functions are more than 10 lines

Comment: @mkhan3189: What does function size have to do with anything? If you want to define functions in headers, then they have to be `inline` to allow multiple definitions and avoid the errors you see. (Perhaps you've got the impression that `inline` forces the optimiser to perform inlining of the function; don't worry, that's not what the keyword means.)

Comment: @MikeSeymour please correct me if I am wrong. The inline under the hood essentially gets the function body and executes it in-line.
also refer to http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Inline_Functions if you like :)

Comment: @mkhan3189: No, the `inline` keyword simply relaxes the one-definition rule to allow definitions in multiple translation units. This *allows* some optimisers to expand them inline, but doesn't *require* them to. If they are large, then it might be a good idea to move the definition out of the header file anyway; but if you keep them there then they *must* be declared `inline`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks for that Mike, Appreciated. 

http://bit.ly/Ntecw3 might clear someone's concept on inline functions.

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to put your functions into a class like this (the following goes to a .h file).  It's probably more common that using nested namespace.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

namespace utils
{
    class StringUtil
    {
        public:
           static void tolower(std::string& str)
           {
               // code
           }
    };
}
```

Comment: Yea I think you are right. But what you think the root cause of the compiler errors?

Comment: You have more than one cpp files (e.g. listing.cpp, match_count.cpp) including your util_strings.h.  Therefore, all your functions in the util_strings.h file appearted to be multipled defined.

Comment: But I have got an include guard there. shouldn't that prevent it?

Comment: The include guard only guard against muliple includes of the same file on the same cpp file.  Each cpp file is compiled separately by gcc (generating the .o object files), and linked together by the linker (ld).  You will notice that you didn't have a "compiler error", rather, you have a "linker error".

Comment: There's nothing "better" about this. One of the reasons for namespaces is to avoid having to define classes that aren't really classes.

Comment: That only "fixes" the problem because the function definitions happen to be inside the class definition, so they're implicitly `inline`. It's simpler to explicitly declare them `inline` without inventing a weird namespace-disguised-as-class to hold them.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I am asking with curiosity to learn. My function has ~60 lines. does that matter? considering the link I sent you on previous link. It's google's style guide that I always follow for my work and personal projects

Comment: The good news is you can usually let the compiler decide what's inline or not, unless you are writing real time (or psuedo real time) systems, or expect these functions to be called thousands of times in a tight loop.  Therefore you can optimize only when necessary.  Personally, 60 lines of inline code does seem excessive, so I would just put the function/class declaration in the header file, and put the function/class definition in the cpp file.

Comment: @LMC 60 lines do not seem excessive? Well have a look at http://bit.ly/Ntecw3, it will help. thanks anyways

Comment: @LMC using 4 inline functions 4 times that are 60 lines (for example) each actually will make your program slower as oppose to having static function calls. means your "one line function call" will be 'replaced' with 60 lines for all 4 functions by compiler making it 240x4 = 960 lines just to use those functions.